# Disable UIPageViewController scrolling when touches start on UISwitch contained in one of the pages

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uiswitch

I have a `UIPageViewController` where one page is a *Settings* screen. On that screen, there is a `UISwitch` to toggle a setting on or off.

While I've noticed many people tap a `UISwitch` to toggle it like I do, I've observed that some users slide a `UISwitch` to toggle it.

Attempting to slide the `UISwitch` can cause problems when it's on a `UIViewController` that's part of a `UIPageViewController`, since sliding the switch can start sliding the `UIPageViewController` as if the user wants to change pages.

This behavior that feels very broken and inconsistent. It seems that if the user touches the switch, but hesitates briefly before sliding, the touches are registered by the `UISwitch` and it works as the user expects. But, if the user touches the `UISwitch` and immediately starts sliding, the `UIPageViewController` gets the touches instead. There seems to be a very fine line (hesitation threshold) between the `UISwitch` getting the touches or not.

**How would you solve this problem?**

Here's an example that starts with simple taps to toggle the `UISwitch`, and then shows some of the different ways to try to slide the `UISwitch` that lead to inconsistent results:

[image: inconsistent-uiswitch-behavior]

---

***Possible Solutions & Issues***

One way I've considered resolving this is to detect touches anywhere on the *Settings* `UIViewController`, and if the touches begin somewhere in the frame of the `UISwitch`, prevent the `UIPageViewController` from sliding.

My worry is that simply disabling sliding for the `UIPageViewController` would not guarantee the touches are passed to the `UISwitch`. That would mean a user might try to slide the `UISwitch` and the `UIPageViewController` would not slide, but the `UISwitch` would also not respond to the touches, making it still seem broken and inconsistent.

To start exploring this possible solution, I've tried detecting touches by overriding the `touchesBegan` method like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("touchesBegan")

    super.touchesBegan(touches,
                       with: event)
}
```

I've tried detecting touches this way on both the `UIPageViewController` and the `UIViewController` of the specific *Settings* page, but neither gets called. I've also tried setting `view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on the views, and different combinations of `true` or `false` on the different `UIViewController`s, but still can't seem to detect touches.

I've also considered just ditching the whole `UIPageViewController` paradigm for this app and making the *Settings* screen a modal instead, since that would resolve the need for this kind of complicated solution, but there are other advantages to the `UIPageViewController` paradigm in the app, so I want to explore whether it'd be possible to keep. Ultimately, that seems like it would be a better idea than weird workarounds, but I wanted to post this anyway in case someone else experiences the same issues or anyone has other possible solutions.

---

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

I spent a ton of time experimenting based on the answers that were submitted, while also learning a lot about how iOS works, so thank you to everyone who answered.

Ultimately, Leon's answer got me going down the path to a simple solution that worked with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, which is very similar to what I was trying with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` based on Carl's answer, but ultimately didn't produce the same results.

I ended up subclassing `UISwitch` and adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that does nothing. This makes it behave exactly as I want: any time a user starts sliding the switch the `UIPageViewController` does not pan.

```
class NoPanSwitch: UISwitch {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self,
                                                action: nil)
        addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page view controller has has `gestureRecognizers` property for gesture recognisers controlling interactions within page. I would try adding a pan gesture recogniser to the `UISwitch` and adding it to page controller.  The effect I would expect is that the pan gesture recogniser of the page controller will require the gesture recognisers in the array to fail before recognising page panning so the scrolling doesn't happen when you flick the switch. If it doesn't work out like that, you might want to swap Page controller for a scroll view with a stack or collection view with your controllers inside. Then you'll have full control over school view's `panGEstureRecognizer` to achieve the above behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Can you subclass the UISwitches you are using?  This sounds more like a job for that class, overriding gestureRecognizerShouldBegin() to return NO for a swipe gesture recognizer moving horizontally.  The documentation for that method mentions that UISlider uses that method for the same purpose; UISwitch should probably do the same.

Another option might be to create a custom UIGestureRecognizer which via delegate or the UIGestureRecognizerSubclass methods forces any other UISwipeGestureRecognizer to fail if it starts over a UISwitch, and is itself set with cancelsTouchesInView to false (and not do anything when it "succeeds").

Comment: Yes, I can subclass the `UISwitch` I'm using. I tried overriding `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin()` on the `UISwitch`, but that's never getting called. I was able to intercept the touches on the `UISwitch` by creating a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and adding that to the `UISwitch`, then making the switch a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and implementing `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer:, shouldReceive touch:)`, but this only lets me detect when the touch starts on the switch, and not when it ends.

Comment: Your second option seems more viable, but I'm having trouble following exactly what you're suggesting. Can you provide any quick code examples in either Swift or Objective-C to illustrate your suggested solution?

Comment: Hmm. Basically you want to disable the UIPageViewController's swipe recognizer when started over a UISwitch.  I thought that is what gestureRecognizerShouldBegin() should do, but guess not.   If you are changing the behavior with a UISwipeGestureRecognizer attached to the UISwitch though, maybe that could do it -- could you set its cancelsTouchesInView property to false, so that touches still get passed to the UISwitch, then have its action do nothing (or call a method which does nothing)?  Its presence may cancel out the UIPageViewController's recognizer, but allow UISwitch to work as normal.

Comment: I tried setting up a simple example, and the UISwitch correctly overrode the UIPageViewController gestures -- every time I touched on it, only the switch would respond.  Maybe the addition of the UITableView is getting in the way somehow.  On the other hand, I see that all the UISwitch implementation is in a private subview, meaning the main UISwitch itself does not get any events (and would not be consulted for overriding recognizers), which defeats most subclass possibilities.  The subview has the switch's recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one and see whether it's working as you want or not.

> 1. Detect the touches on `UISwitch` when `UISwitch` `touchBegan` set delegate and datasource of `UIPageViewController` to `nil.
> 2. On `touchesEnd` set again set `datasource` and `delegate` for `UIPageViewController`.

In this way you will be able to interact with your `UISwitch` as you want.

Comment: I've tried this, but `touchesBegan` is not called in my `UISwitch` subclass unless I set all its subviews to `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`(based on another Stack Overflow answer I found). If I try turning `isUserInteractionEnabled` on the subviews back on once `touchesBegan` is called, the switch doesn't work.

Comment: Also, when I've set `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on the subviews, I'm able to set `delegate` and `datasource` to `nil` on the `UIPageViewController` to prevent it from scrolling, but `touchesBegan` on the `UISwitch` still seems to only be called after a slight hesitation on the switch before sliding it. It seems when I touch and slide quickly, touches are intercepted by something else before being passed to the `UISwitch`, so even if I could get the `UISwitch` to continue to function after `touchesBegan` it doesn't seem like this solution will prevent most of the unintentional scrolls.

Comment: @gohnjanotis thanks for trying this solution. I will check and see how we can solve this.